# ClosedXML is not working with .NETCoreApp2.0

Tags: asp.net, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, closedxml

I am new to Dotnet-core and working on an app which has Excel manipulation.I chose ClosedXML for the same. When I create a sheet I run into the following `issuTypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Drawing.ColorTranslator' from assembly 'System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.e`
I had problems running ClosedXML in .net core. Earlier when I used .netcoreapp1.1, faced some build issues(DataTable and Dataset were not referenced properly) and then I had to upgrade to version 2.0, But still it seems to be not working.
 What are my options

Comment: It would help if you would include steps to reproduce (from start to finish).

Comment: @jereon -I installed ClosedXML from nuget and then tried to execute this piece of code in my controller 

        var workbook = new XLWorkbook();
        var worksheet = workbook.AddWorksheet("Sample Sheet");
        worksheet.Cell("A1").Value = "Hello World!";
        workbook.SaveAs("HelloWorld.xlsx");
this is when I ran into the error , I mentioned in the question

Answer (score 4):

`System.Drawing` is not available on .NET Core 2.0 or .NET Standard 2.0 so ClosedXML will not work on those platforms.

Support for it is planned in .NET Core 2.1, you can track ongoing discussions and work [on this GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/20325).